# Access Query String from View in Model (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to rails (< 1 month), and decided to build a weather app to get my feet wet.
I'm using HTTParty to grab a Weather Underground feed based on Zip code and will be passing weather information through it...

### The short story (What's supposed to happen)

User enters zip code on home page, zip code is passed through URL so HTTParty can serve up the appropriate XML file.

### The Problem

I can't for the life of me get the stupid zip code to make it back to the model where HTTParty is doing its thing.

I've debugged to figure out that:

```
http://localhost:3000/12345
```

Will indeed pass a param - I have it routed to where ?zip=12345 gets transformed into a permalink of sorts:.  Debug dump does show:

```
zip: '37064'
```

So I know the zip code is at least there. However, I need to be able to take that parameter and pass it through to the model containing the HTTParty get request.

Here are the basics:

#### fetch_weather.rb (model), weather_controller, weather#weather (view), routes.rb file

http://pastebin.com/jbrffU08

(One thing worth mentioning: the "37064" will be replaced with the zip code passed through the URL... it's just there for testing purpose)

Obviously I want to do more with this, but here's the starting point.

### My Question

Is this the correct way (the "rails way") to do this?

a) If so, how can I get the query string to update the model like it should so I can get the correct XML feed?

b) If not, what's the "correct" way to do it, and can I at least be pointed in the right direction?

I'm a WordPress-Dev-Turned-Rails-Dev so I'd love any feedback on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models should not be concerned with views, query strings and all that. Their job is to manage data. To manage query strings, however, is job of controller.

```
class WeatherController < ApplicationController
  def weather
    # extract zip code from query string and pass to the model
    @weather_lookup = FetchWeather.new params[:zip]
  end
end

class FetchWeather < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :temperature, :condition, :zip

def initialize zip
  # snip

 self.zip = zip
end

 def fetch_weather
    HTTParty.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/0299ecb9aa94e332/hourly/q/" + zip + ".xml")
 end

end
```

Comment: Here's my new pastebin: http://pastebin.com/j1U5Md6C - now i'm getting a undefined method `stringify_keys' for "37064":String (the additions are for the view)

Comment: @studionashvegas: that means that you have string where you expect a hash. Do some debug printing

Comment: @studionashvegas: also, you have overwritten my constructor with yours. Did you just copy/paste my code, without trying to understand what is there, how it works and why it was done this way?